# Where are the application preference files location on Mac

Tags: macos, plist, preferences, core-foundation

I am having a hard time finding from where my application is picking up its window dock and location settings. I removed the related plist files and folders from the following directories:

1. [USER]/Library/Preferences
2. [USER]/Library/Preferences/By Host
3. [USER]/Library/Caches
4. [USER]/Library/Saved Application State

But the old window settings are retained when I launch the application. The application is using *CFPreferencesCopyValue* method to read preference values:

```
::CFPreferencesCopyValue("Toolbars:MyTools:Application", "kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication", kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
```

I am not very familiar with Mac's preferences mechanism. Can someone explain what could be happening here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This problem hit me recently so I thought I'd post the answer here belatedly.

When you delete the preferences on a Mac (plist file) make sure you clear the cached preferences otherwise Java programs can keep working with the cached settings.
You can:

1. after you have deleted your plist file
2. `killall -u <your-user-name> cfprefsd`

   OR
3. reboot

Items 2. and 3. will cause the cache to be cleared and then your preferences will be reloaded as the cfprefsd restarts automatically.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the command in 2nd step be "killall -u <your-user-name> cfprefsd"?

Comment: Thanks WallTearer.  I changed it to "code" format and now the <your-user-name> displays which I hadn't checked carefully enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `NSUserDefaults` on Mavericks (at least) are cached and it is not recommended to edit the plist files manually. The actual files reside in a container folder (you may know this folder from sandboxing).

But you can use the command line utility `defaults`to edit, change or delete preferences. To delete the defaults (= reset defaults for your app) you can run in terminal:

```
defaults delete com.myapp.* && rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.myapp.*
```

This is taken from a blog entry that shows in [detail explanations on user defaults and mavericks](http://mostafaberg.com/2013/11/nsuserdefaults-issues-on-macosx-mavericks-explained/).